# How to prevent errors from being shown in the view when I have validate_required?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have this code in my `new.eex`:

```
<%= if Enum.any?(@changeset.errors) do %>
  <%= rendering_code_is_here %>
<% end %>
```

The problem that `if` will always be true, because of my changeset has the code:

```
def changeset(struct, params) do
  struct
  |> cast(bla-bla)
  |> bla-bla-bla
  |> validate_required([:title])
end
```

So, in my controller I have:

```
  def new(conn, _params) do
    changeset = Content.changeset(%Content{})
    render conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset
  end
```

So, it will be always invalid (`title` is nil). How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Why do you have `validate_required([:title])` if you accept a `nil` value? Why not remove the validation from your changeset?

Comment: I don't accept a nil value, but I'm expecting to receive something not nil from user. I can't predict what will user type into title, that's why I'm left this field as blank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your changeset will always have an error and therefore the `rendering_code_is_here` will run every time.

What you need to check for is if there are any errors after an `action` (such as `Repo.insert` or `Repo.update`) was performed on the changeset using the [`action`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#module-the-ecto-changeset-struct) field.

```
<%= if @changeset.action do %>
  <%= rendering_code_is_here %>
<% end %>
```